# Background music and shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer

i want to toggle the background music on and off using settings , which is an activity and it can be launched by pressing the menu button through the main activity and selecting *settings*. the problem I am facing now is that when i tick the background music checkbox , upon clicking save and returning to the main activity , my music stops playing. how to i make sure that the music keeps playing after going back to the main activity? And when i stop the app and relaunch the activity , i want the settings to remain the way they were selected (using sharedpreferences). Can anyone take a look at my codes and see what I am doing wrong?

my MainActivity.java

```
package sp.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.setting:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

My settings.java

```
package sp.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    CheckBox Backmusic;
    Button button1;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.xml.preferences);
        Backmusic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.backmusic);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }
    private void loadSavedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value",false);
    if (checkBoxValue){
        Backmusic.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        Backmusic.setChecked(false);
    }
}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value",Backmusic.isChecked());
    if (Backmusic.isChecked()){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound);
        mp.start();
    } else {

        mp.stop();
        finish();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
    finish();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So right now you are just playing the music within your Settings activity. In fact you are calling `mp.stop()` in `onStop()`. That's why when it closes the music stops.

You should also put code in your `MainActivity` in `onCreate()` and `onResume()` to read from sharedpreferences and if the background music is true, play music. That could look something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean backgroundMusic = sp.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value",false);
if (backgroundMusic)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound);
    mp.start();
}
else
{
    mp.stop();
}
```

Note that you'll now want to write to `SharedPreferences` in `Settings` using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`. That way the preferences will be saved across the entire application and not just one activity.

Comment: hi , can you elaborate more on where I am supposed to put the code in the main activity? i am confused whether i am supposed to put it in onCreate or onresume

Comment: Put it in both. That way when you open the app it remembers your settings from the last time, and when you go from `Settings` back to your `MainActivity` it will reflect the new settings.

Comment: Check out the activity lifecycle docs here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Hi , I don't understand totally. as in am i supposed to put the codes in such a way that

Comment: Okay , ignore the previous comment. As in , I am not sure how to alter my main activity and settings. sorry i am quite a newbie and not sure how to alter it :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: As in , can you tell me exactly what I am supposed to alter / change my code ? I am quite clueless :x

Comment: I have indicated exactly what you need to do in my answer. Add something along the lines of the suggested code block to `onCreate` and `onResume` and modify your code in `Settings` to get the `SharedPreferences` object using `getApplicationContext()` in the constructor instead of `this`.

Comment: Hopefully you actually understand what I am saying and are not just looking for something you can copy and paste into your file...?

Comment: I do understand the concepts and i'll try to implement it :) thanks for the help man .

Comment: No problem. And please consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer if it has helped you.